# How can I get top n buckets for an aggregation and all other buckets combined into an "other" bucket?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

Assume a collection with schema like as shown below:

```
{
    "customer" : <unique-id-for-customer>,
    "purchase" : <number>,
}
```

Now, I want to get the the top 5 customers (by purchase-queantity) and the 6th bucket is "others" which combines all the purchase quantity from other customers.

Basically, the output of aggregation should be like:

```
{ "_id" : "customer100", "purchasequantity" : 4000000 }
{ "_id" : "customer5", "purchasequantity" : 81800 }
{ "_id" : "customer4", "purchasequantity" : 40900 }
{ "_id" : "customer3", "purchasequantity" : 440 }
{ "_id" : "customer1", "purchasequantity" : 300 }
{"_id" : "others", "purchasequantity" : 29999}
```

Comment: I think this is not possible with just one aggregation command.

Comment: i too tried my best.. couldn't figure out a way to retrieve the results in a single command. db.aggregations.aggregate([{$sort:{purchasequantity:-1}},{$limit:5}]); and db.aggregations.aggregate([{$sort:{purchasequantity:-1}},{$skip:5},{$group:{_id:'others',totalAmount:{$sum:'$purchasequantity'}}}]); results have to be merged.

Comment: First Aggregation: db.test.aggregate([
 {
  "$sort" : {"purchase" : -1}
 },
 {
  "$project" : {
   _id : '$customer',
   'purchase' : 1
  }
 },
 {
  $limit : 5
 }
])
Second Aggregation: db.test.aggregate([
 {
  "$sort" : {"purchase" : -1}
 },
 {
  $skip : 5
 },
 {
  "$group" : {
   _id : 'other',
   'purchase' : { $sum : "$purchase" }
  }
 }
])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - sort mongodb by the value of one key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797359/python-sort-mongodb-by-the-value-of-one-key)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called [*weighting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighting). To do that you need to add a weight to your documents by [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)ing them and using the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator, then sort them by "weight" in ascending other and by "purchasequantity" in descending order.

```python
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "purchasequantity": 1, 
        "w": { 
            "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$_id", "others" ] }, 1, 0 ] 
        } 
    }}, 
    { "$sort": { "w": 1, "purchasequantity": -1 } } 
])
```

Which returns:

```python
{ "_id" : "customer100", "purchasequantity" : 4000000, "w" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "customer5", "purchasequantity" : 81800, "w" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "customer4", "purchasequantity" : 40900, "w" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "customer3", "purchasequantity" : 440, "w" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "customer1", "purchasequantity" : 300, "w" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "others", "purchasequantity" : 29999, "w" : 1 }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It returns all elements with "w" 0 and the field "_id" as an ObjectID. Also, how do you limit the number of buckets?