# python - sort mongodb by the value of one key

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

I have a collection with below data structure:

```
[{name: "123", category: "A"},
 {name: "456", category: "B"},
 {name: "789", category: "A"},
 {name: "101", category: "C"}]
```

I want to be able to sort them according to the value of `category`, by specifying which comes first. For example, sorting the query in the order of B->C->A, the result would yield:

```
[{name: "456", category: "B"},
 {name: "101", category: "C"},
 {name: "123", category: "A"},
 {name: "789", category: "A"}]
```

Is there any good way of doing so with the mongo query API? I am using [mongoengine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine)

Comment: This is the possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714910/how-can-i-get-top-n-buckets-for-an-aggregation-and-all-other-buckets-combined-in) I can't vote to close because the answer to this question is not upvoted or accepted so added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is using the [`.aggregate()`](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.aggregate) method and the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) conditional operator to add a *weight* to your documents in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage then use the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) aggregation operator to sort your documents by *weight*.

```
pipeline = [{'$project': {'category': 1,
               'name': 1,
               'w': {'$cond': [{'$eq': ['$category', 'B']},
                               1,
                               {'$cond': [{'$eq': ['$category', 'C']},
                                          2,
                                          3]
                               }]
                    }
            }},
            {'$sort': {'w': 1}}
]

Model.aggregate(*pipeline)
```

*Demo using PyMongo*:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> import pymongo
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> collection = client['test']['collection']
>>> pipeline = [{'$project': {'category': 1,
...                    'name': 1,
...                    'w': {'$cond': [{'$eq': ['$category', 'B']},
...                                    1,
...                                    {'$cond': [{'$eq': ['$category', 'C']},
...                                               2,
...                                               3]
...                                    }]
...                         }
...                 }},
...                 {'$sort': {'w': 1}}
...     ]
>>> pprint.pprint(list(collection.aggregate(pipeline=pipeline)))
[{'_id': ObjectId('571caa930e4f55302502a361'),
  'category': 'B',
  'name': '456',
  'w': 1},
 {'_id': ObjectId('571caa930e4f55302502a363'),
  'category': 'C',
  'name': '101',
  'w': 2},
 {'_id': ObjectId('571caa930e4f55302502a360'),
  'category': 'A',
  'name': '123',
  'w': 3},
 {'_id': ObjectId('571caa930e4f55302502a362'),
  'category': 'A',
  'name': '789',
  'w': 3}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is still not possible to provide a custom sorting function in MongoDB:

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-153

You can though, as a workaround, sort in Python, mapping categories to numerical values that would actually be used to sort the documents:

```
from pprint import pprint

weights = {
    "A": 2,
    "B": 0,
    "C": 1
}

docs = db.col.find()
pprint(sorted(docs, key=lambda item: weights.get(item["category"])))
```

Comment: Actually this *jira* is quite old. I wonder why it's still open because since MongoDB version 2.6 you can use the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator to do this server-side. Anyway this will solve the problem but is less efficient than the solution using the native API coded in C++

Comment: @user3100115 oh, wow, did not know that. Great answer! Thanks.

Comment: @user3100115 great example on using `aggregate()`, but do you mind elaborate how is mongo's API coded in C++ more efficient than python?

Comment: @tropicalfish well-written code in statically typed language like C++ are *most of the time* faster than dynamically typed language  like Python why? The answer is out of the scope here. Also note that some operations are better handled server-side and that is precisely why MongoDB provides the [`sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) method the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) update operator and the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) aggregation pipeline operator.